# Unable to sign in to Visual Studio. Encountered unexpected character '<'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am getting an error when signing in Visual Studio:
There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenResponse. Encountered unexpected character '<'.

I have installed the community edition of Visual Studio 2019 on my VM. My evaluation period (30 day trial) has ended and require me to sign in to unlock  the product.  However, I am getting the above error when signing thru Visual Studio. I was able to sign in using my browser.

Is there a solution for this or any workaround? Is this related to firewall or network? or any configuration in Visual Studio?